# How to create a MYSQL Workbench Data Dump using Wizard on MAC?

Tags: mysql, macos, dump

I have a database that I need to share on a MAC and the Data Export wizard to create the dump file will not allow selection of any tables for the database and when created only has just the database name with no tables.  I have also tried the Migration Wizard on the MAC and it still does not transfer the tables and data with the database from the source server to the target server. How can I get the dump file created on the MAC or get the script for the entire database and inserts?